# Mxtoobox: Loop detected! We were referred back to IP

Tags: bind9, dnssec

I followed the tutorial for DNSSEC found in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-dnssec-on-an-authoritative-bind-dns-server--2

Here is my zone file:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400      ; 1 day
example.net       IN SOA  ns1.example.net. root.mailserver.net. (
                                2016091915 ; serial
                                43200      ; refresh (12 hours)
                                300        ; retry (5 minutes)
                                1209600    ; expire (2 weeks)
                                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                                )
                        NS      ns1.example.net.
                        NS      ns2.example.net.
$TTL 60 ; 1 minute
                        A       ...
$TTL 86400      ; 1 day
                        TXT     ...
                        DNSKEY  256 3 7 ...
                        DNSKEY  257 3 7...
$ORIGIN example.net.
ns1                     A       VPS_IP
ns2                     A       VPS_IP
```

In godaddy, I created two hosts (ns1.example.net and ns2.example.net), both linked to the same ip VPS_IP. The zone is configured in a VPS of ip VPS_IP.
Almost everything works, I can successfuly query A and records of my zone, that are correctly ponting to the desired ip.
I checked with (mxtoolbox.com), using 'dns:example.net', and everything is fine, except for a warning saying the nameservers are part of the same subnet (expected since they are the same VPS_IP).
However, when I use (mxtoolbox.com) to check for dns key (dnskey:example.net) I get this message: Loop detected! We were referred back to 'VPS_IP'. All other queries using mxtoolbox.com is fine.
Also, when I try to add the DS records in godaddy, I have this error:

```
We are unable to validate your data at this time. Please try again later. If the problem persists, contact customer support.
```

Are both errors related? What could be wrong in my zone file to get that error from mxtoolbox?

Answer (score 7):

Turn out that the problem is in using the same host for nameserver. They must be different.

Answer (score 2):

I actually fixed this by adding `ns1` and `ns2` A records to the domain name.

```
ns1.janglehost.com. [142.112.212.219] [TTL=172800]
ns2.janglehost.com. [142.112.212.219] [TTL=172800]
```